# How to track all login logs about the jwt in spring security

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt, spring-aop

Recently, I started to make a platform and chose spring security as the back end and angular as the front end. And I want to track all login logs, such as failed login, successful login, username does not exist, incorrect password, etc.

I try to use spring aop to track all login logs, but I only get the logs when the login is successful.
These are the jwt filter and the spring aop code.

```
public class JwtUsernameAndPasswordAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    public JwtUsernameAndPasswordAuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    }

    /* get username and password in user request by jwt */
    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {

        try {
            UsernameAndPasswordAuthenticationRequest authenticationRequest = new ObjectMapper()
                    .readValue(request.getInputStream(), UsernameAndPasswordAuthenticationRequest.class);

            Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                    authenticationRequest.getUsername(),
                    authenticationRequest.getPassword()
            );

            Authentication authenticate = authenticationManager.authenticate(authentication);

            return authenticate;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }
    }

    /* create jwt token when user pass the attemptAuthentication */
    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request,
                                            HttpServletResponse response,
                                            FilterChain chain, Authentication authResult) throws IOException, ServletException {
        String key = "securesecuresecuresecuresecuresecuresecuresecuresecuresecuresecure";
        String token = Jwts.builder()
                .setSubject(authResult.getName())
                .claim("authorities", authResult.getAuthorities())
                .setIssuedAt(new Date())
                .setExpiration(java.sql.Date.valueOf(LocalDate.now().plusWeeks(2)))
                .signWith(Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(key.getBytes()))
                .compact();

        response.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
    }
}
```

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class LoginLogAOP {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoginLogAOP.class);

    @AfterReturning(pointcut="execution(* org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager.authenticate(..))"
            ,returning="result")
    public void afteReturn(JoinPoint joinPoint,Object result) throws Throwable {
        logger.info("proceed: {}", joinPoint.getArgs()[0]);
        logger.info("result: {}", ((Authentication) result));
        logger.info("user: " + ((Authentication) result).getName());
    }

}
```

Has anyone tracked login logs through Spring Security jwt? Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: why are you using a custom jwt filter when there is already a fully implemented jwt filter in spring security?

Comment: @Toerktumlare I'm new to spring security, so I searched for information about spring security with jwt on the Internet, and most people login through a custom jwt filter.

Comment: i recommend you always start out by reading the official documentation of a library before you start any implementation to get the correct information https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#oauth2resourceserver-jwt-architecture a lot of blogs out there are full of faulty information.

Comment: @Toerktumlare I agree with your suggestion, but the official document is really quite complicated, I will take the time to learn it, thank you

Comment: its actually not complicated at all if you just spend some time actually reading the documentation and first reading how spring security is architectured which is also included in the documentation. If you jump into the middle yes, you wont understand anything. Its better to implement something correct, than quick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your advice type `@AfterReturning` does exactly what the name implies: It kicks in after the method returned normally, i.e. without exception. There is another advice type `@AfterThrowing`, if you want to intercept a method which exits by throwing an exception. Then there is the general `@After` advice type which kicks in for both. It is like the supertype for the first two subtypes.

And then of course if you want to do more than just react to method results and log something, but need to actually modify method parameters or method results, maybe handle exceptions (which you cannot do in an "after" advice), you can use the more versatile, but also more complex `@Around` advice.

Actually, all of what I said is nicely [documented in the Spring manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#aop-advice).

---

**Update:** I forgot to mention why `@AfterReturning` does not capture the cases you are missing in your log: Because according to the documentation for [`AuthenticationManager.authenticate(..)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/authentication/AuthenticationManager.html#authenticate-org.springframework.security.core.Authentication-), in case of disabled or locked accounts or wrong credentials the method must throw certain exceptions and **not** exit normally.

Comment: I'm using the afterThrowing and get the bad credentials, but I'm need more error information. I will refer to the file you provided. Thank for you help.

Comment: Be more precise, please. What kind of "more error information" do you need that is not part of the exception? Where does the error information come from? If you explain that, I can tell you how to get your hands on it from inside the aspect. You are a software developer, please talk like one. You should know that precision is important in our line of business.

Comment: As mentioned in the question content, I need to get more types of errors, such as the user name does not exist exception, but when I use @AfterThrowing, I only get BadCredentialsException

Comment: I cannot say anything intelligent about an after throwing advice I cannot see, and it is kind of difficult to debug prose or invisible code.